# Django post_save receiver won't save foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have three models: `User` (from `django.contrib.auth.models`), `UserProfile` and `GameCharacter`.

I setup the following receivers so when a `User` is created, a `UserProfile` and a `GameCharacter` are automatically created as well.

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        user_profile = UserProfile()
        user_profile.user = instance
        user_profile.money = 0

        user_profile.save()


@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=UserProfile)
def create_user_profile_character(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.character = GameCharacter()  # Doesn't work, `character_id` is NULL in databse
        instance.character.save()
        instance.save()
```

As expected, it creates two entries in database, a `UserProfile` and a `GameCharacter`, **but the foreign key to the `GameCharacter` is** ***not*** **saved**, it's `NULL` in database.

It's as if the line `instance.character = GameCharacter()` didn't exist.

My models:

```
class GameCharacter(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    server = models.ForeignKey(GameServer, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    is_bot = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, default=None)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    character = models.ForeignKey(GameCharacter, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    money = models.BigIntegerField()
```

I use **MySQL** and **InnoDB** as storage engine.

Any idea?

Comment: Can't both be done in create_user_profile signal ?

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal Yes, but it was not working in `create_user_profile(...)` so I tried a different way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to create a GameCharacter object. 
Then link it to instance.character

ie:

```
character = GameCharacter()
character.save()
instance.character = character
instance.save()
```

Comment: I can't believe it! It works! How does this differ from `instance.character = GameCharacter()`, then `instance.character.save()`, then `instance.save()`? I don't get it.

Comment: When you just do, GameCharacter() the object is created only. It is not saved to the db yet. That is why you can't link it to another model.